# Add a default image if there is not image in the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on this [pen](http://codepen.io/mohammadhamza/pen/mfHzJ).All I want to do is if there is no image in the post then default image should be shown.The Jquery I've used is

```
$(function () {
     $(".post").each(function () {
 var posthead = $(this).find("h2.post-title").text(),
             postlink = $(this).find("h2.posttitle a").attr("href");
       if($(this).find("img:first")>=1){
         var imageSrc=$(this).find("img:first").attr('src');
       }
       else{
         var imageSrc="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-P5H7BaGibPg/UjVD-0SIs9I/AAAAAAAADFk/l65svtw9IHg/s320/70-photography-2.jpg";
       }
                $(this).replaceWith("<div class='post'><img class='thumb' src='" + imageSrc + "'/><div class='posthead'><h2 class='hometitle'><a href='" + postlink + "'>" + posthead + "</a></h2></div></div>");
     });

 });
```

According to above if there is an image then its attribute src should be as a var imageSrc but if it is not else condition having a image should be as var imageSrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if an image is present you need the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the jQuery object

Replace

```
if($(this).find("img:first")>=1){
```

for

```
if($(this).find("img:first").length>=1){
```

Here's the **[updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvfIm)**

Comment: Thnks bud,this is what I want looking for

Comment: @MohammedHâmzã Glad to help. Don't forget to mark the answer as accept it if it resolved your issue